# How to automatically uninstall DirectX 9?

Tags: wix, directx, uninstallation

I am putting together a WiX installer that includes silently installing DirectX 9:

```
dxsetup.exe /silent
```

How do I tell WiX how to un-install DirectX? Is there another switch on the command line?

I need to be able to configure the installer to un-install DirectX automatically, else users complain if they can't uninstall.

Comment: Are you sure it is safe to do this?  If a user installs your app, then installs another app that also requires DirectX 9, then uninstalls your app, the other app will break since you've uninstalled DirectX 9.  In general, system dependencies like this (e.g. CRT, .NET runtime, etc.) are installed by apps but never uninstalled since there's no system in place to keep track of all dependent apps on the system.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was just trying to uninstall DirectX because users were complaining that sometimes my app would not un-install. I now believe it was due to other factors, not DirectX. I won't do it again!  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *DirectX End-User Runtime* (aka DirectSetup or DXSETUP), it has long been recommended that you don't even try to uninstall it.

In any case, on most versions of Windows you can't 'uninstall' DirectX and running DXSETUP doesn't actually "Install DirectX" either as it's built into the OS. It can only be updated by installing a new version of the OS, installing a Service Pack, or applying a Windows Update. This applies to all versions of Windows starting with Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, and Windows XP x64 Edition.

DXSETUP is still useful for deploying stuff like legacy D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, XACTEngine, XAudio 2.7, XInput 1.3, D3DCompile #43 or earlier, etc. It just doesn't ever install "DirectX".

See [No So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx). If after reading this article you still think you need to run DXSETUP as part of your deployment, you should pick up the latest version of [DXSETUP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update.aspx) to avoid some potential issues, and [trim it down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805.aspx#small_installation_packages) to just those CABs you *actually use* in your application.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I will leave well enough alone. The reason I was inquiring is because the previous installer that I used (InstallShield) did not uninstall properly, and I assumed it was because of DirectX. I have switched to WiX and the application itself now seems to uninstall correctly. However, I'm having a different set of problems with WiX (posted separately). Thank you.